# mysqli function doesn't insert values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to a database by mysqli in an object oriented way. I had a few errors, and solved them, but now I just can solve this one. I've got my code here, and all the names (database name, user, password, host, and table names) are correct (actually, copied and pasted), but the query still returns 0.

```
<?php


class DbConnection
{
    public $link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","todo");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
    }

    function RegisterUsers($username, $password, $ip, $name, $email)
    {
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username, `Password`, ip, Name, Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $ip, $name, $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
        return $count;
    }

}

$dbConn = new DbConnection();
echo $dbConn->RegisterUsers("a","a","a","a", "a");


?>
```

**Edit:** With this code, i get an

> Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

error.

[image: This is my database]

Comment: are you getting any errors?  or use 
    printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error); to print errors

Comment: Yes, I got an error, didn't have the Email value. Now I get a `Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean` error. I updated the code @Naisapurushotham

Comment: add another placeholder to `bind_param`. It should look like this `bind_param("sssss",$username, $password, $ip, $name, $email)`. One placeholder for each parameter, same for the `?` markers, you need five of them

Comment: The ?, didn't remember them... 
That solved it! Thank you so much! @AlexAndrei
Could you please post it on an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`Password` and `name` are  [keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql. You have to put it in backticks to escape it, if you will use it as column name

```
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username, `Password`, ip, `Name`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: @user6463207 check for errors after execute statement: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Please, see my edit and comments on my post to solve my actual problem, thanks

Comment: @user6463207 now you have 5 column names and only 4 place holder in `values`. Please do not change the question, add all changes as updates to the question

Comment: Question changed, and code updated. Now I have the bind_param() with 5 string values and 5 variables.